# Removing controls from a windows form if another menu strip option is clicked

Tags: c#

I have a menu strip in place that when clicked upon, adds controls and shows them on the windows application I am making. However, when I try to click on another option and attempt to hide the previous controls shown, it does not hide itself but merely stays on the screen and the datagridview is shown on top of it. I tried the `Hide()` method but that does not appear to be working.

Here is my code (the `AddControls` method I made, where it is called, and the `HideAllControls` method I also made)

Add Controls -

```
private void AddControls()
{
    // begin household head controls

    Label householdHeadLbl = new Label()
    {
       Name = "lbl_householdHead",

       Text = "Household Head"
    }; 


    householdHeadLbl.Font = new Font(householdHeadLbl.Font.FontFamily, 12);

    householdHeadLbl.Location = new Point(86, 75);

    householdHeadLbl.Size = new Size(130, 24);

    ////////////////////////////////////////////
    TextBox houseHoldHeadTextBox = new TextBox()
    {
       Name = "txtBox_householdHead"
    };

    houseHoldHeadTextBox.Font = new Font(houseHoldHeadTextBox.Font.FontFamily, 12);

    houseHoldHeadTextBox.Location = new Point(220, 72);

    houseHoldHeadTextBox.Size = new Size(154, 24);

    // add the controls 
    // household head controls
    Controls.Add(householdHeadLbl);
    Controls.Add(houseHoldHeadTextBox); 
}
```

(There are more controls but I went past the 30000 character limit)

Menu Strip Insert Member Click -

```
private void MenuInsertMember_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddControls();
}
```

HideAllControls -

```
private void HideAllControls(Control ctrl)
{
    foreach (Control c in Controls)
    {
       if (c is TextBox || c is Label)
       {
           c.Hide();
       }
       else
       {
           break;
       }
    }
}
```

Menu Strip View Click -

```
private void MenuViewMembers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // hide any controls left that may be left over from another option
    HideAllControls(this);
}
```

I included a screenshot to help show/explain what I am encountering.

Insert screenshot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXXK9.jpg

View screenshot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWjXe.jpg

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are trying to "swap views", why not use a `TabControl` and switch tabs?  There are simple ways to hide the tabs, btw, so you could get the benefit without actually seeing the tabs themselves.

Comment: wasn't aware of that (new to C#..)

Comment: It's a nice trick, I've used it a lot.  It's worth asking why you are creating controls in code instead of laying out the form in designer.

Comment: because I was creating the controls based on if the menu insert was clicked.

Comment: but if I wanted to keep the menus and do it that way, is there a way?

Comment: That `break` statement is a bug.

Comment: Remove the else statement with break as @HansPassant  said